# What's the maximum size of cargo that fits into the Chinese Y-20 cargo plane?

Tags: cargo, china

Somewhat related to [this Skeptics question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53134/was-the-chinese-ship-da-cui-yun-carrying-materials-for-building-wmd), what's the maximum *size* object that fits through the door into a Y-20 cargo plane?

Would an 18 x 4 meter cylindrical item fit in? I can [find](https://www.indiastrategic.in/topstories1959_China_%20Xian_Y-20_Airborne.htm) the maximum weight an Y-20 can carry, but that's not terribly conclusive with respect to dimensional limitations of its cargo hold.

The Y-20 can carry Type 15 tanks, but those are only 3.3 metres wide (and 2.5 metres high).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all this picture from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MilitaryPorn/comments/2lrkx6/chinas_xian_y20_transport_alongside_a_uae_air/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=mweb3x) gives a general idea of the size of the Y-20 compared to C-17:
[image: Y-20 with C-17]
([link to picture source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hgBh.jpg)) While the Y-20 is in the foreground, the C-17 still looks about the same size, so the Y-20 would be smaller than the C-17.

This article: [globalsecurity.org - Y-20 Kunpeng - Design](https://www.globalsecurity.org/military/world/china/y-20-design.htm) provides a comparison of cross sections of the C-17 and Y-20, which does coincide with the percieved size difference seen in the picture above:
[image: cross sections C-17 Y-20]

The article further notes:

> Compared with the Il-76, the Y-20 seemed to have a shorter wingspan and a shorter, but slightly wider, fuselage [5.4 meters versus 4.8 meters]. The Y-20 is larger than the Airbus A400M and has about the same fuselage diameter, but is much smaller than the Boeing C-17.

and:

> The IL-76 has a narrow cargo compartment that limits the size of the load. The Xian Y-20 is closer to the of C-17 cabins, i.e. within 4.0-4.5 meters height and width and approximately 20-25 meters in length.

The [cargo hold of C-17 is 548cm wide](https://www.af.mil/About-Us/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/1529726/c-17-globemaster-iii/), and if the picture above is reliable, the given appriximate dimensions of the cargo hold of the Y-20 match (well this is pretty much a circular argument).

If the information above is correct, even with some play, Y-20 should be able to fit a 18x4 meter cylinder (as long as the 18 is the length, and 4 is the diameter). The rigidity and other properties of that object might however make it impossible to load it on the Y-20, as it might require substantial reinforcements around it.